# Would it be possible to make text become highlighted after linking to it?

Tags: html

I don't think I really explained that well in the title so I'll try describe a bit more.
Currently I am using `<a id="x">` and `<a href="#x">` in order to link parts of a page to a table of contents. I would like to be able to have the linked text become highlighted after clicking on its link(does that sound right?) so that its a bit more clear which part you read.

Comment: Why not just use anchor tags https://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html

Comment: What's the difference between what I'm using now and that?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to do that sooner! I don't think I was able to do it? Could it have to do with being a new user

Comment: @videogamelover, Yes, many new users forget to do this. Do not worry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For links like anchors, you can use the pseudo-class `:target`.

```css
:target {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#id1">one</a>
<a href="#id2">two</a>
<a href="#id3">three</a>

<div id="id1">one text</div>
<div id="id2">two text</div>
<div id="id3">three text</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is what you want.

```css
:target {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#heading"><div id="heading">HEADING</div>
</a>
<a href="#subheading1"><div id="subheading1">SubHeading 1</div>
</a>
<a href="#subheading2"><div id="subheading2">SubHeading 2</div></a>
```